# Ruby / ROR - Syntax Error Keyword END (All blocks have end)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Getting the following error:

```
syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting keyword_end
```

and

```
syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end
```

with code

```
  <% if user.admin? do %>
        <%= form_tag({:controller => '/admin/link', :action=> 'link', :id => @link.id}) do %>

        <%= render :partial => "link_form" %>

        <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

Though i have been through the code about 10 times, all my blocks are closed. The answer may be very easy since i am a ruby/ror newbie. Also the code is not very difficult, only about 15 lines.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems like you have an extra 'do'. First line should just be

```
<% if user.admin? %>
```

Comment: Ahh thanks *face palm* i knew it was something simple. Do you know of a good tutorial on when you require a do block and when not (even an SO post), cant accept the answer right now. Will do as soon as i can. Thanks!

Comment: A do block is simply a looping construct, for example <% foo.each do |v| %>, which loops through each element in foo.  An if statement never requires a do block, as the code within is implicitly executed if the if statement is true